# How to close swipeabledrawer within different class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-props, react-state

I'm a little bit confused with the SwipeableDrawer explanation on the Material-ui website. Basically I have a Component 'Sidebar' which opens a SwipeableDrawer if a user clicks on button on the appbar, or a user swipes to open up the sidebar.

In the appbar there's a button you can press which gets passed to the parent component.

```
// Topbar.js
<IconButton color="inherit" onClick={onSidebarOpen}>
   <MenuIcon/>
</IconButton>

// Main.js
<Topbar onSidebarOpen={this.handleSidebarOpen}/>
```

The handelSidebarOpen method sets a state of whether the sidebar is open or closed. So now the problem is that I'm not entirely sure how to tell the Sidebar properly to open or close the drawer if a user swipes the drawer open.

I used this approach

```
<Sidebar
  open={this.state.openSidebar}
  onClose={this.handleSidebarClose}
/>
```

And then in the Sidebar class I do this

```
// Inside render method
const {open, onClose} = this.props;

return (
  <SwipeableDrawer
        open={open}
        onOpen={event => this.showDrawer(event)}
        onClose={onClose}
        disableBackdropTransition={!iOS}
        disableDiscovery={iOS}
      >
        {console.log(onClose)}
        {this.fullList()}
  </SwipeableDrawer>
);
```

Please feel free to ask me for clarification if you don't understand the problem. I've made a little demo to show the problem.

https://codesandbox.io/embed/dazzling-galileo-mc3oz?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Try to swipe the sidebar open and watch what happens. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass `handleSidebarOpen` method in Sidebar at your Main.js file.

```
<Sidebar
   open={this.state.openSidebar}
   onOpen={this.handleSidebarOpen}
   onClose={this.handleSidebarClose}
/>
```

Get that function in your Sidebar.js and use it on onOpen attribute of SwipeableDrawer. Like below,

```
const { open, onOpen, onClose } = this.props;

return (
      <SwipeableDrawer
        open={open}
        onOpen={onOpen}
        onClose={onClose}
        disableBackdropTransition={!iOS}
        disableDiscovery={iOS}
      >
        {console.log(onClose)}
        {this.fullList()}
      </SwipeableDrawer>
    );
```

I have also created sandbox for you;

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-gki1u?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark